# Abstraer rectangulos de imagenes y guardarlos en una colección

Tags: c#, imagen

En esta ocasión estoy necesitando extraer cada una de las figuras coloreadas y guardarlas en una colección. Para ello, uso una imagen de plantilla que yo mismo armé para trabajar.

[image: Imagen de plantilla]

El código que tengo es el siguiente... pero lo único que logré al momento es marcar con puntos donde se encuentran las esquinas. Mi dificultad en este momento es tomar los puntos detectados y armar una coleccion de rectángulos.

[image: Con los puntos obtenidos dibujo en la imagen circulos]

```
public static List<CrosshairModel> ExtractImagesFull(string path)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
        //Hago fondo transparente al blanco para localizar los marcos
        bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White);

        List<CrosshairModel> pointers = new List<CrosshairModel>();

        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                CrosshairModel cm = new CrosshairModel() {
                    Top = ((y - 1) < 0 ? Color.Transparent : bmp.GetPixel(x,(y - 1))),
                    Right = ((x + 1) >= bmp.Width ? Color.Transparent : bmp.GetPixel((x + 1), y)),
                    Bottom = ((y + 1) >= bmp.Height ? Color.Transparent : bmp.GetPixel(x, (y + 1))),
                    Left = ((x - 1) < 0 ? Color.Transparent : bmp.GetPixel((x - 1), y)),
                    Center = bmp.GetPixel(x, y),
                    PointerPosition = new Point(x,y)
                };

                //Superior izquierda
                if (cm.Top.A == 0 && cm.Right.A == 255 && cm.Bottom.A == 255 && cm.Left.A == 0 && cm.Center.A == 255)
                {
                    cm.Corner = CrosshairModel.CornerType.TopLeft;
                    pointers.Add(cm);
                } //Superior derecha
                else if (cm.Top.A == 0 && cm.Right.A == 0 && cm.Bottom.A == 255 && cm.Left.A == 255 && cm.Center.A == 255)
                {
                    cm.Corner = CrosshairModel.CornerType.TopRight;
                    pointers.Add(cm);
                }//Inferior izquierda
                else if (cm.Top.A == 255 && cm.Right.A == 255 && cm.Bottom.A == 0 && cm.Left.A == 0 && cm.Center.A == 255)
                {
                    cm.Corner = CrosshairModel.CornerType.BottomLeft;
                    pointers.Add(cm);
                }//Inferior derecha
                else if (cm.Top.A == 255 && cm.Right.A == 0 && cm.Bottom.A == 0 && cm.Left.A == 255 && cm.Center.A == 255)
                {
                    cm.Corner = CrosshairModel.CornerType.BottomRight;
                    pointers.Add(cm);
                }
            }
        }

        return pointers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien cómo lo has planteado y tampoco sabemos cómo funciona CrosshairModel, yo te planteo la solución a tu problema de la siguiente forma con un método que devuelve una lista de tipo Rectangle con todos los rectángulos calculados de las figuras de una forma intuitiva y optimizada:

```
public List<Rectangle> DetectingRects(Image p_ImgSource, Color p_BackgroundColor)
{
    int colorFondo = p_BackgroundColor.ToArgb();

    Bitmap bmpCanvas = new Bitmap(p_ImgSource);

    // Lista donde iremos añadiendo los rectángulos encontrados
    List<Rectangle> Rects = new List<Rectangle>();
        
    for (int y=0; y < p_ImgSource.Height - 1; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x < p_ImgSource.Width - 1; x++)
        {
            if (bmpCanvas.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb() != colorFondo)
            {
                // Candidato a ser una esquina de una de las figuras
                Point curTopLeftCorner = new Point(x, y);

                // Investigamos si el punto pertenece ya a un rectángulo
                bool IsInsideExiting_Rect = false;
                for(int i=0; i < Rects.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Rects[i].Contains(curTopLeftCorner))
                    {
                        IsInsideExiting_Rect = true;
                        x = Rects[i].Right  ; // Para optimizar evitamos recorrer el 
                                              // ancho del rectángulo ya calculado
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Si ya pertenece a un rectángulo calculado volvemos al bucle
                // con x ya optimizada para ahorrar cálculos.
                if (IsInsideExiting_Rect) continue;
                    
                // Si el punto no se encontraba en ninguno de los rectángulos
                // calculados, entonces era la esquina de la figura y ahora
                // vamos a encontrar la esquina opuesta.
                int dx = 0;
                while (colorFondo != bmpCanvas.GetPixel(x + dx, y).ToArgb())
                {
                    if (++dx + x >= bmpCanvas.Width - 1) break;
                }
                int dy = 0;
                while (colorFondo != bmpCanvas.GetPixel(x, y + dy).ToArgb())
                {
                    if (++dy + y >= bmpCanvas.Height - 1) break; 
                }
                // Incorporamos el reactángulo calculado a nuestra lista
                Rects.Add(new Rectangle(x,y,dx,dy));

                // Para optimizar, evitamos investigar dx pixeles
                x += dx;
            }
        }
    }
        
    // Devolvemos nuestra lista con los resultados.
    return Rects;
}
```

Una vez que disponemos de un método capaz de calcular los rectángulos de las figuras, podemos crear otro que nos permita extraer las propias figuras:

```
public List<Image> ObtenerImagenes(Image p_ImgSource, Color p_BackgroundColor)
{
    // Aquí llamamos a nuestro método creado anteriormente para obtener los rectángulos
    List<Rectangle> Rects = DetectingRects(p_ImgSource, p_BackgroundColor);
    // Y esta nuestra lista donde situaremos las imágenes
    List<Image> listImages = new List<Image>();

    // Recorremos la lista de rectángulos calculados para ir incorporando las imágenes
    foreach(Rectangle rect in Rects)
    {
        Bitmap bmpCROP = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
        Graphics gCrop = Graphics.FromImage(bmpCROP);
        gCrop.DrawImage(p_ImgSource, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmpCROP.Size),
                        rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        listImages.Add(bmpCROP);
    }
    // Devolvemos la lista con las imágenes
    return listImages;
}
```

Comment: Gracias Antonio por tu respuesta desestimalo ya lo he resuelto.

Comment: Como no lo habías indicado, creía que seguía vigente la pregunta.

Comment: En estos casos si encuentras una solución lo suyo es que la publiques, podrás ayudar a otros que tengan el mismo problema y además evitas que, como en mi caso, dedique un tiempo de forma innecesaria.

Comment: Mil disculpas aunque llevo años en stack realmente soy bastante nuevo participando, lo solucione con Aforge.net, con eso puedo extraer los rectángulos en pantalla.